# Unable to show questions of the second page

Tags: javascript, python, css, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a flask app, where there're questions paginated in 2 pages,
the problem is that clicking on the number 2 to change the page doesn't change the questions, I don't know which part of the code should be responsible for that, if there any code snippets required to help solving this problem just tell me to edit the question.

[image]

[image]

**backend**

```py
def paginate_questions(request, selection):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    start = (page - 1) * QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE
    end = start + QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE

    questions = [question.format() for question in selection]
    current_questions = questions[start:end]

    return current_questions
```

```py
    @app.route('/questions')
    def get_paginated_questions():
        categories = Category.query.order_by(Category.id).all()
        selection = Question.query.order_by(Question.id).all()

        current_questions = paginate_questions(request, selection)

        if len(current_questions) == 0:
            abort(404)

        return jsonify({
            'success': True,
            'questions': current_questions,
            'total_questions': len(selection),
            'current_category': None,
            'categories': {category.format()['id']: category.format()['type']
                           for category in categories}
            })
```

**frontend**

```js
  getQuestions = () => {
    $.ajax({
      url: `/questions`, //TODO: update request URL
      type: "GET",
      success: (result) => {
        this.setState({
          questions: result.questions,
          totalQuestions: result.total_questions,
          categories: result.categories,
          currentCategory: result.current_category })
        return;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        alert('Unable to load questions. Please try your request again')
        return;
      }
    })
  }

  selectPage(num) {
    this.setState({page: num}, () => this.getQuestions());
  }
```

Comment: You added the "page" buttons, didn't you?  So you must know what web request they are going to generate.  That request will, presumably, receive the page number to display.

Comment: Share your code too so we can see what you have/haven't done